# Contar arrays dentro de array PHP

Tags: php, array, contador

Boas pessoal, tenho o seguinte array

```
[[],[{"id":3,"image_name":"47440_planet_mars.jpg","path":"59c1d5ddd862547440_planet_mars.jpg","imageable_id":9,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41"}],[],[],[],[{"id":5,"image_name":"50066_space_mission_space_shuttle_before_launch.jpg","path":"59c1d5de36aa950066_space_mission_space_shuttle_before_launch.jpg","imageable_id":2,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:42","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:42"},{"id":4,"image_name":"48542_space_mission_iss.jpg","path":"59c1d5ddd904048542_space_mission_iss.jpg","imageable_id":2,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41"},{"id":2,"image_name":"oh5Ef7w.jpg","path":"59c1d5dd91752oh5Ef7w.jpg","imageable_id":2,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41"},{"id":1,"image_name":"SGHRgHo.jpg","path":"59c1d5dd8f85aSGHRgHo.jpg","imageable_id":2,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41"}]]
```

Eu preciso contar quantos valores existem dentro de cada array, no caso o resultado tem que ser:
[0,1,0,0,0,5]

Pensei de várias formas aqui mas não obtive resultado.

Agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não percebi bem se queres fazer isso em JavaScript ou PHP uma vez que tens uma array em formato de JavaScript. Se fôr um JSON precisas de usar `json_decode` em PHP.

#### JavaScript:

```js
var arr = [[],[{"id":3,"image_name":"47440_planet_mars.jpg","path":"59c1d5ddd862547440_planet_mars.jpg","imageable_id":9,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41"}],[],[],[],[{"id":5,"image_name":"50066_space_mission_space_shuttle_before_launch.jpg","path":"59c1d5de36aa950066_space_mission_space_shuttle_before_launch.jpg","imageable_id":2,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:42","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:42"},{"id":4,"image_name":"48542_space_mission_iss.jpg","path":"59c1d5ddd904048542_space_mission_iss.jpg","imageable_id":2,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41"},{"id":2,"image_name":"oh5Ef7w.jpg","path":"59c1d5dd91752oh5Ef7w.jpg","imageable_id":2,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41"},{"id":1,"image_name":"SGHRgHo.jpg","path":"59c1d5dd8f85aSGHRgHo.jpg","imageable_id":2,"imageable_type":"App\\Assay","created_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41","updated_at":"2017-09-20 02:43:41"}]];
var resultado = arr.map(el => el.length);
console.log(resultado);
```

#### PHP

Em PHP precisas combinar o `json_decode` com `array_map` e `count`, a função nativa para saber o numero de elementos numa array.

```
Ficaria assim:

$string = '
[
  [],
  [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "image_name": "47440_planet_mars.jpg",
      "path": "59c1d5ddd862547440_planet_mars.jpg",
      "imageable_id": 9,
      "imageable_type": "AppAssay",
      "created_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:41",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:41"
    }
  ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "image_name": "50066_space_mission_space_shuttle_before_launch.jpg",
      "path": "59c1d5de36aa950066_space_mission_space_shuttle_before_launch.jpg",
      "imageable_id": 2,
      "imageable_type": "AppAssay",
      "created_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:42",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:42"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "image_name": "48542_space_mission_iss.jpg",
      "path": "59c1d5ddd904048542_space_mission_iss.jpg",
      "imageable_id": 2,
      "imageable_type": "AppAssay",
      "created_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:41",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:41"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "image_name": "oh5Ef7w.jpg",
      "path": "59c1d5dd91752oh5Ef7w.jpg",
      "imageable_id": 2,
      "imageable_type": "AppAssay",
      "created_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:41",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:41"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image_name": "SGHRgHo.jpg",
      "path": "59c1d5dd8f85aSGHRgHo.jpg",
      "imageable_id": 2,
      "imageable_type": "AppAssay",
      "created_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:41",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-20 02:43:41"
    }
  ]
]
';

$arr = json_decode($string, TRUE);
$resultado = array_map("count", $arr);
var_dump($resultado); // array(6) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(0) [5]=> int(4) }
```

Nota: Em PHP creio que `App\\Assay` tem caracteres inválidos, não sei bem de onde vem esse JSON, por isso tirei no exemplo.